# Use typedef within struct for naming and indexing text commands

Tags: c++, c, c-preprocessor

I am working with a simple command line application that takes in ASCI text and interprets it as a command.

I have attempted to minimize the redundancy in this application via the example at http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/cpp/Concatenation.html.

eg:
Consider a C program that interprets named commands. There probably needs to be a table of commands, perhaps an array of structures declared as follows:

```
 struct command
 {
   char *name;
   void (*function) (void);
 };

 struct command commands[] =
 {
   { "quit", quit_command },
   { "help", help_command },
   ...
 };
```

It would be cleaner not to have to give each command name twice, once in the string constant and once in the function name. A macro which takes the name of a command as an argument can make this unnecessary. The string constant can be created with stringification, and the function name by concatenating the argument with `_command'. Here is how it is done:

```
 #define COMMAND(NAME)  { #NAME, NAME ## _command }

 struct command commands[] =
 {
   COMMAND (quit),
   COMMAND (help),
   ...
 };
```

Now, let's say that I want to have a command string and index (ie: int) value, rather than a string and function pointer.

```
 struct command
 {
   char *name;
   int command_idx;
 };
```

Now, I have a means to name commands, and have some sort of index I can use later on to identify each command programatically. For example, I have a switch statement that operates on the command index. If I want to work on these indexes, I have to manually set the values first.

I can manually create an enumerated data type, but then I have define the enumerated constants in a separate enum statement. IE:
enum commands { cmd_quit = 0, cmd_help }
and in the end, I still end up having to type each command name twice: once via the COMMAND() macro, and again in my enum.

Is there any method using the C preprocessor that would allow me to create a macro creates the "command" struct (with string and int members), and auto-numbers the int value (command_idx) as I add more commands via the COMMAND() macro?

I am also aware that I can just use strcmp() calls on each possible command, and compare to the input provided by the user, but I would like to have a direct means of indexing into commands via the command_idx value, as opposed to strcmp'ing against a massive list of commands each time (ie:  O(1) instead of O(n) ). I also want to avoid having to type the command name more than once at all costs.

Thanks!

Comment: Why you would want an index? You are better off with a function pointer...

Comment: Some compilers have a `__COUNTER__` macro. You could use that.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use macro redefinition to achieve this.  First, you create a file that simply lists your commands called `commands.inc`:

```
COMMAND(quit)
COMMAND(help)
...
```

Then, in your C source you can `#include "commands.inc"` multiple times, with different definitions of `COMMAND()` in effect to control how it works.  For example:

```
struct command
{
   char *name;
   int command_idx;
};

#define COMMAND(NAME) CMD_ ## NAME,

enum command_enum {
#include "commands.inc"
};

#undef COMMAND

#define COMMAND(NAME) { #NAME, CMD_ ## NAME },

struct command commands[] =
{
#include "commands.inc"
};

#undef COMMAND
```

(Note that this particular example relies on a C99 improvement that allows a trailing `,` at the end of the lists in the `enum` declaration and compound initialiser - you can easily work around that in C89 by adding a dummy entry at the end).

Comment: Perfect. This is exactly what I wanted.

Answer (score 2):

Question:

> Is there any method using the C preprocessor that would allow me to create a macro creates the "command" struct (with string and int members), and auto-numbers the int value (command_idx) as I add more commands via the COMMAND() macro?

Yes, and since you have tagged the question also as C++:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <map>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

map< string, int >     commands;

bool register_cmd( int id, string const& name )
{
    commands[name] = id;
    return true;
}

#define COMMAND( name ) \
    int const name ## _cmd = __LINE__; \
    bool const name ## _reg = register_cmd( name ## _cmd, #name )

COMMAND( exit );
COMMAND( help );
COMMAND( do_stuff );

int cmd_id( string const& name )
{
    auto const it = commands.find( name );
    return (it == commands.end()? -1 : it->second );
}

int main()
{
    for( auto it = commands.begin();  it != commands.end();  ++it )
    {
        cout << it->first << " => " << it->second << endl;
    }
    
    cout << "Gimme a command, please: ";
    string cmd;  getline( cin, cmd );
    switch( cmd_id( cmd ) )
    {
    case exit_cmd:
        cout << "You typed an EXIT command, which has id " << exit_cmd << endl;
        break;
    default:
        cout << "Hey, why not try an 'exit' command?" << endl;
    }
}
```

I just used `map` instead of fancy new C++11 hash table because `map` works with older compilers and no real need for shaving nano-seconds here.

Comment: Thank you. I now have both a C99 and C++ means of achieving this. Thank you all for your assistance!

Comment: You could probably eliminate the `bool` variables by having `register_cmd()` return `id`, then using `int const name ## _cmd = register_cmd(__LINE__, #name)`