# Resolve build warning - "extra tokens at end of #include directive"

Tags: c, struct, compiler-warnings, suppress-warnings

I am testing a solution I tried in a previous question: [Use typedef within struct for naming and indexing text commands](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7961217/use-typedef-within-struct-for-naming-and-indexing-text-commands)

However, I would like to keep my compiler warnings to none. I use static code analysis tools for this purpose, and in the case of certain tools (ie: LINT) I can manually exclude certain rules and warnings on a per-line basis using markup within my comments.

In the case of the first/top answer, I tried that solution, but modified the final structure to look like so:

```
struct command commands[] =
{
#include "commands.inc",
{NULL, NULL}
};
```

This is so I can know if, during a search, that I've reach the largest addressable member of this array-of-struct and not get an out-of-bounds condition. The problem is that I know have a compiler warning, "Warning: extra tokens at end of #include directive". Is there any way to disable this warning? I like this solution, and it suits my needs very well.

---

---

In the end, I updated my .inc file to be like so:

```
CMD(list),
CMD(quit),
CMD(start),
```

instead of

```
CMD(list),
CMD(quit),
CMD(start)
```

I then was able to remove the trailing commas from both my macro definitions and from my static initialization code.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You should remove the comma at the end of your `#include` directive.  It should not be there.

Comment: I need it there so I can declare the next element consisting of nulls.

Comment: @GirLovesTacos:  then move the comma to the next line.  A line beginning with `#` is for the preprocessor and won't be seen by the compiler.

Comment: You really don't need that comma,- it SHOULD be generated with #define,- like in your suggested SO link - `#define COMMAND(NAME) { #NAME, CMD_ ## NAME } , ` ...

Answer (score 1):

It's probably upset about the trailing comma.  Try:

```
struct command commands[] =
{
#include "commands.inc"
, {NULL, NULL}
};
```

Comment: Unfortunately, that causes a compiler error and breaks the build.

Comment: Ah I didn't notice the macro already has the comma built in.  Then @Tony The Lion's comment is correct.  The macro will give you the comma you need to declare the next element consisting of NULLs.