# Replace "getter" function with macro-type lookup

Tags: c, linux, gcc, macros, c-preprocessor

## Problem

I am attempting to port over a large platform abstraction library (PAL) for multiple hardware-based products to a small embedded system with limited resources (i.e. **kilobytes count**).

The current PAL has a simple `getRegister()` function which returns a register address for a specific product. For example, assuming products named `coconut` and `pineapple`, the code will look something like so:

```
#include "headers/Include/coconut.h"
#include "headers/Include/pineapple.h"

enum prodType {
    PROD_COCONUT = 0,
    PROD_PINEAPPLE,
    PROD_MAX,
    PROD_INVALID = (-1)
};

uint64_t getRegister(enum prodType prod, int regName) {
    uint64_t r = 0;

    switch (prodType) {
        case PROD_COCONUT:
            switch (regName) {
                case REG_BASE:
                    r = COCONUT_REG_BASE;
                    break;
                case REG_CORE:
                    r= COCONUT_REG_CORE;
                    break;
            }
            break;
        case PROD_PINEAPPLE:
            switch (regName) {
                case REG_BASE:
                    r = PINEAPPLE_REG_BASE;
                    break;
                case REG_CORE:
                    r= PINEAPPLE_REG_CORE;
                    break;
            }
            break;
        default:
            // Error.
            break;
    }

    return r;
}
```

---

## Goal

I would like to change this function to be a simple, compile-time macro equivalent, so that `getRegister(PROD_COCONUT, REG_BASE)`, would just look into a table of values and return the appropriate register value. The reason for this is so that, if I know a platform will only support `coconut`, I can use macros to not include the headers for other products (i.e. `pineapple`), and reduce program size.

---

## Work So Far

So far, I am considering something like so:

```
enum regs {
    REG_BASE = 0,
    REG_CORE,
    REG_MAX,
    REG_INVALID = (-1)
};

struct keyValPair {
    int idx;
    enum reg;
    uint64_t val;
};

struct keyValPair tableCoconut[] = {
    { 0, REG_BASE, COCONUT_REG_BASE },
    { 1, REG_CORE, COCONUT_REG_CORE },
};
```

So, I'd like to be able to do something to the effect of indexing into the table so that `tableCoconut[REG_BASE]` returns `COCONUT_REG_BASE`, **returning a value in `O(1)` time without having to iterate/search through the table.** Ideally, it's a compile time macro expansion rather than a real function call.

---

## Question

Is there a (simple/clean) way to implement some intermediate mapping so that:

- I can drop the `idx` variable from my `keyValPair` struct (**optional**).
- Have a `O(1)` (i.e. non-search based lookup) for the mapping (**required**)?

This is assuming the register values are non-contiguous and unique? [I'm considering using pieces from a slightly similar question of mine from years ago](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7961217/use-typedef-within-struct-for-naming-and-indexing-text-commands), but can't quite get this bijective sparse-to-contiguous mapping going with macros. I was trying to maybe create an auto-incrementing index value via macros and `##` operations to create an intermediate index with a prefix attached to `REG_BASE`/`REG_CORE` via the `##` concatenation operation with the preprocessor.

## Edit

Not all products have the same registers. There may be a `banana` product down the line that doesn't supply an entry for `BANANA_REG_CORE`.

Comment: Why would including headers increase your program size?

Comment: @melpomene If I were to do a giant, `numProducts` by `numRegisters` array for dozens of products as opposed to a single product, the lookup table becomes massive.

Comment: Even if you make `getRegister` an inline function?

Comment: @melpomene Yes, even in that case. I'm trying to minimize the number of bytes by removing functions if an array-of-struct makes it smaller.

Comment: Is `getRegister` always called with constant arguments?

Comment: @melpomene I can't guarantee it. On the non-embedded platforms, unlikely. On the embedded, it will always be constants.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given that your enum starts at 0 and goes up sequentially from there, you can use the enum value to index directly into an array and retrieve the value you want.  While this probably won't happen at compile time, an array lookup is O(1) so it should be fast.

So you could build an array like this:

```
uint64_t tableCoconut[] = {
    COCONUT_REG_BASE,
    COCONUT_REG_CORE
};
```

And `tableCoconut[REG_BASE]` or `tableCoconut[REG_CORE]` will give you the value you want in O(1).

You can further expand this to account for multiple products:

```
uint64_t tableAll[2][2] = {
    { COCONUT_REG_BASE, COCONUT_REG_CORE },
    { PINEAPPLE_REG_BASE, PINEAPPLE_REG_CORE },
};
```

And perform O(1) lookups like `tableAll[PROD_COCONUT][REG_BASE]` or `tableAll[PROD_PINAPPLE][REG_BASE]`

Comment: @DevNull For products that don't have a particular type of register, you can put a dummy value in the table.